# submit form on click function error in geo autocomplete

Tags: html, forms, click

Am using following `google geo autocomplete`

**code**

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" id="location">
            <input id="geocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Type in an address" value="" />
            <fieldset>
                <h3>Address-Details</h3>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" value="">
                <label>Latitude</label>
                <input name="lat" type="text" value="">
                <label>Longitude</label>
                <input name="lng" type="text" value="">
                <label>Formatted Address</label>
                <input name="formatted_address" type="text" value="">
                <input type="submit" name="submit">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.7.0/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
                    details: "form",
                    types: ['geocode', 'establishment'],
                    country: 'in'
                });
                $("#find").click(function () {
                    $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
                    $("#location").submit();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

as per code the form should `submit` once i select location from `autocomplete` but it doesn't

**Note: can someone help me solve issue with `input button` or without `input button`**

How do i submit form on select`(click ()function)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think automatically submitting a form when the user selects something is a good idea. They won't have time to make sure the correct result was sent or to correct a mis-click. That being said, here you go:

From the docs:

> ### Events
>
> You can subscribe to events of the geocode plugin by using the default
>   jQuery syntax:
>
> ```
> $("input")
>   .geocomplete()
>   .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
>     console.log(result);
>   });
> ```
>
> The following events are supported:
>
> - `"geocode:result"` - Geocode was successful. Passes the original result as described
>     [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html#GeocodingResults).

In your example:

```
$("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
    details: "form",
    types: ['geocode', 'establishment'],
    country: 'in'
})
.bind('geocode:result', $('#location').submit());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @user3080953 answer is correct, you can pass any callback you want to geocomplete,
another example:

```
$("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
    details: "form",
    types: ['geocode', 'establishment'],
    country: 'in'
})
.bind('geocode:result', function(event, target){
    $("body").css("background-color", "red");
    $('#location').submit();
});
```

you can see more hooks here in [geocomplete documentation](https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) (events part).